# What is a good strategy for database cennection in continuous Python script?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have continuous Python script that parses certain websites or XML's every 30 second and adds records o database if it turns out, there is something new.

First, I was just connecting to database every time which I knew, wasn't ideal way how to do it. i had something like this:

```
def job():

    try:
       cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASSWORD, host='XYZ', database=DB_NAME)
       cursor = cnx.cursor()

        # CALLS OF PARSERS:

        run_parser1(cnx, cursor)
        run_parser2(cnx, cursor)
        # etc...

    except Exception as e:

        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()

schedule.every(30).seconds.do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now I edited my code so connection is open until there is an exception either in connecting to database or in parsing:

```
try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASSWORD, host='XYZ', database=DB_NAME)

    cursor = cnx.cursor()

except Exception as e:
  
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
def job():

    try:
        alert_list = CAPParser(getxml()).as_dict()

        # CALL OF PARSERS:

        run_parser1(cnx, cursor)
        run_parser2(cnx, cursor)
        # etc...

    except Exception as e:

        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()


schedule.every(30).seconds.do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

However, there is problem. While I know it's secure way to do it, it means that I need to restart script several times per day. There are a lot of exceptions either from lost database connection or unavailable URL's of parsed sites or files.

Any advice how to find better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a function which verifies if the cnx is open and if it's not, recreate it. Something like:

```
def job():
  global cnx
  global cursor
  if not cnx.is_connected(): # Uses ping to verify connection
    try:
      cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASSWORD, host='XYZ', database=DB_NAME)
      cursor = cnx.cursor()
    except Exception as e:
      cursor.close()
      cnx.close()
      # You can do this try in a while with a delay to keep retrying to connect
  ... # job here
```